# Parse duration time string

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse duration strings like

*1h30m40s* or *56m12s*

in PHP. I try the following the Regexp

```
^(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+)s$
```

But it didn't work with strings like *56m12s*.
How can i make the the hours optional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) non-capturing group around the given subpattern.

```
^(?:(\d+)h)?(\d+)m(\d+)s$
```

If you are just wanting to validate these strings, you can remove the unnecessary capture groups.

```
^(?:\d+h)?\d+m\d+s$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `?` for zero or one occurrence. No need for parentheses in the other parts of the regex:

```
^(\d+h)?\d+m\d+s$
```